# How do I remove item from Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Ok I don't know how but one of my form is stuck in Visual Studio common items and I don't know how to remove it.

All I did is copy the original form say form-x and pasted it in solution explorer.

This screenshot shows the issue:

[image: Issue picture.]

And now I have no idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Create item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2022), find the item template location and delete it.

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio <version>\My Exported Templates.`